# Send Values from Rest api Sharepoint to Ga Method (Google Analitycs)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile

I have the following problem I get properties of the current user logged in sharepoint but when I send the Ga method in Google Analytics I see the result as "undefined".

Additional things:

-The server is sharepoint online.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var DisplayName;  
var Email;
var PersonalUrl;
var PictureUrl;
var Title;
var UserUrl;
var Departamento;


var reqUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties";  
$.ajax({  
    url: reqUrl,  
    type: "GET",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
    },  
    success: successHandler,  
    error: errorHandler  
});  

function successHandler(data) {  
    console.log(data);  
    DisplayName = data.d.DisplayName;  
    Email = data.d.Email;  
    PersonalUrl = data.d.PersonalUrl;  
    PictureUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;  
    Title = data.d.Title;  
    UserUrl = data.d.UserUrl;  
    Departamento = data.d.Deparment;

   /* alert("DisplayName: "+ DisplayName +"\n"+
          "Email: "+ Email +"\n"+
          "PersonalUrl: "+ PersonalUrl +"\n"+
          "Title: "+ Title +"\n"+ 
          "UserUrl: " + UserUrl +"\n"+ 
          "Departamento:" + Departamento);*/
}  

function errorHandler(error) {  
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
}  

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-111314177-1', 'auto');

  ga('set', '&uid','Usuario');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', DisplayName); // undefined
  ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Area');
  ga('set', 'dimension3', 'Cargo');
  ga('set', 'dimension4', 'Tipo de Horario');
  ga('set', 'dimension5', 'Rol');
  ga('set', 'dimension6', 'Tipo de Empleado');
  ga('set', 'dimension7', 'Gerencia Central');

  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Here my dimesion in GA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WWmp.jpg)

Comment: The GA method does not return anything, so the result is undefined. That does not mean it does not send anything - look into the network tabs for tracking requests (starting with /collect?v=1).

Comment: Dear, 
could you give me an example please